# Folium choropleth map leaving blank with Chrome and Firefox on Jupyter notebook

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, jupyter-notebook, geojson, folium

I'm trying to display a choropleth map of France with Jupyter notebook using Folium but it doesn't work, it leaves a blank (without error messages) even with other browsers than Chrome. I believe my code is OK and there aren't mistakes but for some reason it doesn't work. I tried to save the map to HTML also but no effect.

[Click here to have access to my files and my code](https://www.notion.so/Help-choropleth-map-e25b07d723d1432bae93d561b39a4270)

[Here is a screenshot of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmFg3.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the apostrophe `'` in the title of your map (you can choose a title like "Montant aide"). In order to have your choropleth working, you need to change the type of the "code" from strings to numbers (remove the quotes) :

```
"properties":{"code":11,"nom":"Île-de-France"}
```